# Delete the smartpointer object?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Background:
While reading about the smart pointers I came across the following sample implementation for Smart Pointer in C++

```
template < typename T > class SP
{
    private:
    T*    pData; // Generic pointer to be stored
    public:
    SP(T* pValue) : pData(pValue)
    {
    }
    ~SP()
    {
        delete pData;
    }

    T& operator* ()
    {
        return *pData;
    }

    T* operator-> ()
    {
        return pData;
    }
};

class Person
{
    int age;
    char* pName;

    public:
        Person(): pName(0),age(0)
        {
        }
        Person(char* pName, int age): pName(pName), age(age)
        {
        }
        ~Person()
        {
        }

        void Display()
        {
            printf("Name = %s Age = %d \n", pName, age);
        }
        void Shout()
        {
            printf("Ooooooooooooooooo",);
        } 
};

void main()
{
    SP<Person> p(new Person("Scott", 25));
    p->Display();
    // Dont need to delete Person pointer..
}
```

Questions:

1. This smart pointer gives the benefit that it deletes the Person class object once it goes out of scope. But then do we need to specifically add the code "delete p;" in the main function so that smart pointer class do not leak itself?
2. Since the Person class also has the destructor function, do we really need to call the delete on person's object? The destructor would be automatically called when Person object goes out ofscope

Comment: Don't use this implementation. I don't know where you found it but I have a feeling it's a bad source and you should avoid it for learning serious C++. This implementation violates the rule of three, which makes it harmful.

Comment: You don't need to create your own smart pointers any more, the standard library have good implementations that you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[1] You do not need to delete `p` as you allocate it on the stack. If you did:

```
SP<Person>* p = new SP<Person>(new Person("Scott", 25));
```

then you would have to delete it.

[2] You do not need to call `delete` on the `Person` object. That is done by the smart pointer - it is its purpose after all.

So your code does not have any memory leaks at its current state.
The smart pointer implementation, however, lacks a copy constructor, assignment operator, etc. so they should be added to avoid some future undesired behaviour.

Comment: @Lyubomir : thanks for the answers  with Q[2] I meant to ask that Since person class has a destructor defined, so even if we do not use smart pointer for Person, the person class object would get destroyed in its destructor call when it goes out of scope?

Comment: It does not depend on whether or not it has a destructor. Rather it depends on how a variable is declared. Assuming a smart pointer is not used, if `p` is `Person* p = new Person();` then you have to manually call `delete` when you are finished with `p`. If `p` is `Person p();` then the variable is on the stack and will be destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope.

Comment: That means to summarize: The destructor is called only for the variables on stack,

Answer (score 1):

Don't use that implementation. Use the following classes (in order of preference):

`std::shared_ptr` / `std::unique_ptr` (C++11).
`std::tr1::shared_ptr` / `std::tr1::unique_ptr` (Pre-C++11 support in Vis Studio 2008).
`boost::shared_ptr` / `boost::unique_ptr` (If the smart pointer classes above don't exist in your compiler).

Comment: While your remarks are sensible, they did not answer the OP's questions. +1 nevertheless, to offset the -1.